# Searching a field containing multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mariadb

Suppose  i need a field called `skills` in my table.It should store various skills of a person such as `php`,`java` , `Golang` .

What would be the appropriate approach  to store such data in the database so that it make searching by skill easier

**Edit 1**

The user can enter anything he wants for skills , above was just an example

The user may type one or more skills in the textbox,separated by commas

Example

```
skill1,skill2,skill3
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example of what you mean by your **Edit 1**.

Comment: Don't understand why this was downvoted! It's a pretty good illustration of the case where to use `SET` columns.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably rethink your design approach and store these skills in a related table called `skills` with columns `skill_id` and `skill_name` and `skill_desc`, etc... then use a cross-reference table to link `person_id` from your table of people, and the `skill_id` from the `skills` table.

If you cannot perform a redesign, you can use a query with a series of `LIKE` calls:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE skills LIKE '%php%' 
   OR skills LIKE '%java%' 
   OR skills LIKE '%Golang%';
```

But that is rather sloppy. I would go with a redesign. Using `LIKE` will negate any benefit of indexes.

To expand on the multiple tables above, when a user types in a list of comma separated skills, you would need to parse that into a collection/array, check for their presence in the new `skills` table. If it doesn't exist you insert it. Then, or if it does exist, you pull the `skill_id` and insert that into the `person_skills_xref` table with the `person_id` (if that combination does not already exist).

This way you can then do a select statement like:

```sql
SELECT s.skill_id, s.skill_name, s.skill_desc
FROM skills s
JOIN people_skills_xref ps
ON s.skill_id = ps.skill_id
WHERE ps.person_id = @personID;
```

That will get you all of the skills for the person with the `person_id` of `@personID`.

Or you can select all of the people in the `people` table with a particular `skill_id` with the following query:

```sql
SELECT p.person_id, p.person_name, p.person_email
FROM people p
JOIN people_skills_xref ps
ON ps.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE ps.skill_id = @skillId;
```

Or by `skill_name` using `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT p.person_id, p.person_name, p.person_email
FROM people p
JOIN people_skills_xref ps
ON ps.person_id = p.person_id
JOIN skills s
ON s.skill_id = ps.skill_id
WHERE s.skill_name LIKE @skillName;
```

Where `@skillName` would contain a search string of `'%sql'` to match anything ending in `sql`, such as `mysql`, `pl/sql`, or just `sql`.

Comment: check edit...user can enter anything for skills so i don't know skills beforehand

Comment: I'm not sure how that changes what I recommended. With a M:M relation on `people` to `skills` via a `people_skills_xref` table, you can put any number of skills on any number of people, in any combination. Plus you wont be duplicating your skills. There would only require one entry in the `skills` table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 3 tables :

```
User
-----------------
id
name

Skill
-----------------
id 
name

User_Skill
-----------------
user_id
skill_id
```

Table User contains all your users, table Skills contains all available skills and table User_Skills join the two tables. So if you want to add a skill to an user you should insert value in table User_Skill.

If you want to retrieve all skills of an user you can use :

```
select s.* from Skills s left join User_Skills us on us.skill_id = s.id where us.user_id = <insert user id>;
```

Comment: [_Optimal Many:Many table schema_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

Answer (score 1):

IMO the more simple (and easily used, at the same time) way for what you need is to use a unique column of SET type.

Basic summary of how it works:

- definition of the field: something like `skills SET('php','java','goLang',...)`
- populating the field (with one or more skills at once): `UPDATE table SET skills = 'php, java'`
- looking for a given skill: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('java', skills) > 0`

Look at this [MySQL page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html), assuming MariaDB should offer the same capabilities.

IMPORTANT NOTE: I think this is the *only* method giving you the needed powerful, because of something you didn't clearly said in your OP, but is likely a requirement: a given person may have *several* skills!

2nd IMPORTANT NOTE: the OP's edit states

> The user can enter anything he wants for skills

This is the only point where `SET` doesn't work *directly* as needed, since the different possible values have to be registered at the column definition level (but obviously can be updated to evolve).
So if user wants to mention some currently-unknown skill, you must offer to him a way to "claim for" this new skill be registered, then register it in the definition column, and actually update the user `skills` field.

Comment: claim for method seems awesome...stackoverflow style:)

Comment: @user2650277 As a non-native English speaker I can't know how my words sound: from your comment I guess I didn't choose the right way to express... Also I wrote this answer rather quickly so it's somewhat abbreviated. What I mean with "claim for" is: the user should have a proposed list of (registered) skills, from where he'll select what he wants. And this list should include something like `other', which when selected leads to an input area where to type the new skill. Then your back-end script should detect this case and process it accordingly (modifying the col def before updating table).

Comment: I understand perfectly what you mean.I wanted to say that stackoverflow also uses the suggestion system you are refering

Comment: @user2650277 Oh! So I now understand I misunderstood your previous comment :) Again, as non-native speaker, it frequently happens that I'm not sure of anything. Notably because "awesome" can be "impressive" as well as "terrific", so I didn't know if it should be read positively or negatively. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the appropriate approach to store such data in the
>   database

You should have a separate table called `Skills` where all the skills should be present and it should also have a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing the parent table `PRIMARY KEY` field.

So that, when needed you can `JOIN` with parent table and `GROUP BY` the parent table key field (`GROUP_CONCAT()` if you want to list all skills) and get all the associated skills